# Sci-Fi Novel, lots of story twists. One part has them surgically altered to go and live with cavemen

Tags: story-identification

This story is vast, and also has single man spaceships, where they have contests on planet involving stripes or grids. The best pilots go out to find in space portals to other areas. One character is a blind telepath of a strict religious sect.

One part the main character is injured or frozen and taken to a water-world where dolphins repair him and give him computer enhancements. The main character's friend at beginning of story are discussing if they had immortality and how he would not get bored, if he got tired of females he would try males, but not part of the story, just a characterization.

Oh, the main character's mom is some sort of witch like person that may have stolen some DNA from her brother to make her son.

I am pretty sure the author's name begins with a Z.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Key-Out-Time-Andre-Norton-ebook/dp/B01DI2WNWE?

Comment: That Andre Norton story has some similarities, but is not the right story. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: valorum is not the story I am looking for, but it does certainly have similarities! Another part of this story the Blind Telapath collects "samples" of DNA from the males in the cavemen community, this caveman part of the story was a search for the perfect DNA, I think to find a key to ageing. This story had lots going on and I thought at the time that the Author was a genius, and wanted to see if he wrote other things.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17631/great-theorem-help-name-the-sci-fi-book-read-long-ago

Answer (score 9):

This is [Neverness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverness) (1988) and the sequel trilogy, [A Requiem for Homo Sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Requiem_for_Homo_Sapiens),  consisting of *The Broken God* (1992), *The Wild* (1995), and *War in Heaven* (1998) by [David Zindell](http://davidzindell.com/neverness/).

## [image]

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer, but you should explain why you think so.