# Novel with a hyperspace pilot who goes to supernova party, falls in love with god who becomes a planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

I once read a great book that started off with the main character- who was a (mathematically-specialized) hyper-space pilot/(and I wanna say assassin)- that was attending a supernova viewing party.  Later he falls in love with a God who becomes a planet and manifests herself from a pool on said planet.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! It's recommended that you take the [tour], to understand how the site works. Also, look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for suggestions for additional information you could edit into your question. For instance: Do you remember when you read this book? Do you have an idea how old it might have been then? Do you recall anything about the cover? What was the focus of the story - the relationship with the god/pool? or was that a side story?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - An excellent edit

Comment: I once fell in love with a girl who was a god-slash-swimming pool. Then I sobered up and realised I was lying in a puddle.

Comment: It sounds so much like *Hitchhikers* but not in a funny way.

Comment: I'm so excited!  In all my years on this site, this is my first time with a definitive identification that 100 other people haven't gotten to first! :)

Comment: @Valorum: While "Neverness" is written in a strange style that reminds me of Cordwainers Smith's "Instrumentality of Mankind" stories, it is not quite as weird as the questions suggests. I'd even say it is significantly nearer to realism than Cordwainers Smith's stories, which usually sport only a loose connection to real science.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17631/great-theorem-help-name-the-sci-fi-book-read-long-ago

Answer (score 10):

This is definitely a book by [David Zindell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Zindell), most likely *Neverness.*  The woman who becomes a godlike cybernetic entity is called the "Solid State Entity" (encompassing not just a planet, but an entire solar system) and she's one of several such AI deities in the book, and in that larger fictional continuity, which is also the setting for his trilogy, *A Requiem For Homo Sapiens* (*The Broken God*, *The Wild*, *War in Heaven*).

One of the most distinctive aspects of the continuity is the existence of a guild of hyperspace pilots who navigate through the universe by discovering new and unique mathematical theorems.

*Neverness* is one of my favorite books, but I never read the trilogy, so the only reason I hesitate at all about the identification is because I don't remember the supernova viewing party.  The mathematical pilots and the Solid State Entity are both in *Neverness*, but they are likely to also appear in the trilogy as well.